# Image conversion in Windows Forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, image-conversion

I hope I get this in the right area, super new here.
I am working on image conversion in windows forms.

My code is:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

Public Class ImageConversion
     Private currentFile As String
     Private image As Image

      Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
        With OpenFile 
            .Title = "Open Image File" 
            .Filter = "Bitmap Files|*.bmp" + 
                "|Enhanced Windows MetaFile|*.emf" + 
                "|Exchangeable Image File|*.exif" + 
                "|Gif Files|*.gif" + 
                "|Icons|*.ico" + 
                "|JPEG Files|*.jpg" + 
                "|PNG Files|*.png" + 
                "|TIFF Files|*.tif" + 
                "|Windows MetaFile|*.wmf"
            .DefaultExt = "jpg" 
            .FilterIndex = 6 
            .FileName = "" 
        End With
        OpenFile.ShowDialog() 
        If OpenFile.FileName = "" Then 
            Return
        End If
        currentFile = OpenFile.FileName.ToString() 
        image = Image.FromFile(OpenFile.FileName) .
        PictureBox1.Image = image
        Me.Text = "Image Conversion -" & OpenFile.SafeFileName.ToString() 
    End Sub

    Private Sub BitmapToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BitmapToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim newName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(currentFile)
        newName = newName + ".bmp"
        If SaveFile.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Try
                Image.Save(SaveFile.FileName, ImageFormat.Bmp)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to save image to bitmap.", "Error" & ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                Return
            End Try
            MessageBox.Show("Image File Saved To" + SaveFile.FileName.ToString(), "Image Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is then repeated for each additional file type. Whenever going to convert my file type doesn't change to the desired conversion nor does the save option give me the choice to pick and it actually doesn't save it as anything other than file type: File.
Attached is a snippet of what happens when the save pops up.
 
I feel like there is something simple I am missing here.

[image]

Comment: You should make use of the `Image Converter` Class

Comment: @Jimi : Actually he isn't just changing the extension. His code loads the selected image into memory (which always uses the same format: an uncompressed memory bitmap) and then saves it, specifying the format to use. GDI+ takes care of the rest.

Comment: @preciousbetine : The `ImageConverter` class is used to convert an `Image` to/from different _data types_. To convert an image into a different format you've got to use the [`Bitmap.Save(String, ImageFormat)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_String_System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageFormat_) overload.

Comment: @VisualVincent yeah that works.

Comment: @TravisRoberts : You set the `Filter` property for the `OpenFile` dialog but you never seem to do the same for the `SaveFile` dialog (unless you do so through the designer). Is this the case?

Comment: @Visual Vincent  Ah, yes, you're right. Pretty careless opinion formed before I edited the question, having seen `GetFileNameWithoutExtension(currentFile) newName = newName + ".bmp"` in the melting pot. Thanks for noticing. I'll delete the previous comment.

Comment: @Visual Vincent Do I need to set a filter if I'm attempting to we'll say "force" it to save as the converted file type?

Comment: @Visual Vincent I was just under the thought that Dim newName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(currentFile)
        newName = newName + ".bmp"
        If SaveFile.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Try
                Image.Save(SaveFile.FileName, ImageFormat.Bmp)

Comment: @Visual Vincent that this would run the save as that .bmp. Sorry each time I hit the return jey on my cellphone it enters the comments t

Comment: @VisualVincent You sir are great! Just had to add:
With SaveFile
           [ .Filter = "Bitmap Files|*.bmp" 'Filters applied to type of file allowed to be converted to = Bitmap Files.
 End With
Right before the If statement and that made it work. I didn't think I needed to with the imageformat command but I guess so. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help! Technically you don't need to add a filter, but if you want it to add the `.bmp` extension automatically you should. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your original class to add some missing features:

- The selected File Format returned by the `SaveFileDialog()`
- The selection of Filters in `SaveFileDialog()` is reduced to the formats that [Image.Save()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Drawing.Image.Save);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) actually supports
- `IDisposable` support, used to dispose of the Bitmap that is currently loaded
- Some others details you can find in the notes and in the class code

This is now a stand-alone class that can be used in other contexts (there's no reference to specific controls or methods:

**Sample usage**:

Initialize the `ImageConversion` class (in a Form's constructor or where you think is appropriate):

```
Public Partial Class Form1
    Public imgConversion As ImageConversion = New ImageConversion()
    '(...)

End Class
```

Your handlers can be modified like this:

```
Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click

    If PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
    Dim NewBitmapFile = imgConversion.OpenFile()
    If NewBitmapFile.OpenedBitmap IsNot Nothing Then
        PictureBox1.Image = NewBitmapFile.OpenedBitmap
        Me.Text = NewBitmapFile.FileName
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BitmapToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BitmapToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim SavedFile = imgConversion.SaveFileFormat()
    If SavedFile.ErrorMessage <> String.Empty Then
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to save image to Bitmap.", "Error" & SavedFile.ErrorMessage, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    ElseIf SavedFile.FileName <> String.Empty Then
        MessageBox.Show("Image File saved to: " + SavedFile.FileName, "Image Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
End Sub
```

Dispose of the `ImageConversion` class when the Form is closed, this will free the last Image object used:

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
    imgConversion.Dispose()
End Sub
```

**To note**:

1. Since you are using a method that returns a `Bitmap` object and this object is then assigned to a `PictureBox.Image` property, you need to dispose of the previous Image, if any, before assigning a new one. Otherwise this *lost* object will linger on more that it's desired and it this will hamper you app.
2. The Filters, in the `SaveFileDialog`, have beed reduced to the `ImageFormats` that are actually supported by GDI+ when creating a new Bitmap.
   `Icon`, `WMF`, `EMF` and `Exif` are  not supported and the resulting Image will be a `PNG` file format, the default GDI+ format.
   The first three can be created with other means, but this is a broad matter and can't be addressed here.
3. A couple of methods return a [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples), in the form of `ValueTuple(Of T1, T2)`.
   I'm not sure your VB.Net version supports this return type and form.
   If not, the method can be modified to return `ByRef` results or a specialized public object (a sub-class of `ImageConversion`) that holds the required informations (probably preferable).

   ```
   Public Function OpenFile() As (OpenedBitmap As Image, FileName As String)
   '(...)
   Dim result = OpenFile()
   Dim img As Bitmap = result.OpenedBitmap 
   Dim fName As String = result.FileName
   ```

---

**The `ImageConversion` class:**

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.IO

Public Class ImageConversion
    Implements IDisposable

    Private IsDisposed As Boolean = False
    Private CurrentFile As String
    Private CurrentBitmap As Image

    Private Enum FilterType
        OpenFile
        SaveFile
    End Enum

    Public Function OpenFile() As (OpenedBitmap As Image, FileName As String)
        Using OFD As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
            With OFD
                .CheckFileExists = True
                .CheckPathExists = True
                .RestoreDirectory = True
                .Title = "Open Image File"
                .Filter = GetFileFilters(FilterType.OpenFile)
                .FilterIndex = 4
                .FileName = ""
            End With
            If OFD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Cancel Then Return Nothing

            CurrentFile = OFD.FileName
            If CurrentBitmap IsNot Nothing Then CurrentBitmap.Dispose()
            CurrentBitmap = CType(Image.FromFile(CurrentFile).Clone(), Bitmap)
        End Using
        Return (CurrentBitmap, CurrentFile)
    End Function

    Public Function SaveFileFormat() As (FileName As String, ErrorMessage As String)
        Dim NewFileName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CurrentFile)
        Dim ErrorMessage As String = String.Empty
        Using SFD As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog()
            With SFD
                .AddExtension = True
                .ValidateNames = True
                .CheckPathExists = True
                .RestoreDirectory = True
                .Title = "Save Image File"
                .Filter = GetFileFilters(FilterType.SaveFile)
                .FileName = NewFileName
            End With

            If SFD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Cancel Then Return (String.Empty, String.Empty)
            Try
                NewFileName = SFD.FileName
                Dim imgFormat As ImageFormat = GetImageFormat(NewFileName)
                CurrentBitmap.Save(NewFileName, imgFormat)
            Catch ex As IOException
                NewFileName = String.Empty
            End Try
        End Using
        Return (NewFileName, ErrorMessage)
    End Function

    Private Function GetImageFormat(FileName As String) As ImageFormat
        Dim fileType As String = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(Path.GetExtension(FileName).Remove(0, 1).ToLower())
        If fileType = "Tif" Then fileType = "Tiff"
        If fileType = "Jpg" Then fileType = "Jpeg"
        Dim imgFormat As ImageFormat = New ImageFormat(New Guid())
        Return DirectCast(imgFormat.GetType().GetProperty(fileType).GetValue(imgFormat), ImageFormat)

    End Function

    Private Function GetFileFilters(Filter As FilterType) As String
        Dim Filters As String() = {
            "BMP Files|*.bmp", "|GIF Files|*.gif", "|JPEG Files|*.jpg",
            "|PNG Files|*.png", "|TIFF Files|*.tif", "|Enhanced Windows MetaFile|*.emf",
            "|Exchangeable Image File|*.exif", "|Icons|*.ico", "|Windows MetaFile|*.wmf"
        }

        Select Case Filter
            Case FilterType.OpenFile
                Return String.Join("", Filters)
            Case FilterType.SaveFile
                Return String.Join("", Filters.Take(5))
            Case Else
                Return String.Empty
        End Select
    End Function

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If IsDisposed Then Return
        If disposing Then
            If CurrentBitmap IsNot Nothing Then
                CurrentBitmap.Dispose()
            End If
        End If
        IsDisposed = True
    End Sub
End Class
```